# alternative to audioContext.copyToChannel() in Safari and Edge

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio-api, microsoft-edge

Both Safari and Edge do not support the `audioContext.copyToChannel()` function to populate an audioBuffer with custom content. Is there any other way to do it?

In my case, I want to create an impulse response, populate a buffer with that response and convolve some sound with that buffer. For Chrome and Firefox this works:

```
buffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(numOfChannels, 1, sampleRate);
buffer.copyToChannel(impulseResponse, 0);
buffer.copyToChannel(impulseResponse, 1);
convolverNode.buffer = buffer;
```

Comment: To hopefully save a few people some time, note that `copyToChannel()` and `copyFromChannel()` are not supported on iOS as of writing this comment. You can use `TypedArray.set()` but I've found that this is very slow.

Comment: Still not supported in Safari.

Comment: why both caniuse.com and mdn declare "full" support on Safari while it doesn't???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use `getChannelData(channel)` on the `AudioBuffer`, you then get a regular `Float32Array` than you can modify at will. Maybe you want to look at the `set` method ?

`copyToChannel` is there to optimize buffer copies , as noted in the [spec](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioBuffer-copyToChannel-void-Float32Array-source-long-channelNumber-unsigned-long-startInChannel) (see the little green box below.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

edge now supports copyToChannel (tested on edge 38.14393.0.0)