# Copy Float32Array to new AudioBuffer in Safari and Edge

Tags: javascript, safari, microsoft-edge, web-audio-api

Here's the landscape: I need to take a `Float32Array` representing a channel from a buffer and copy that to a new `AudioBuffer`. The `copyToChannel` method on the buffer is not available in those browsers even though MDN says it should be. The app fails with that method `undefined`.

So I've tried what this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer/getChannelData) does to copy data from one channel array to another. But that results in `SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern` on the `OfflineAudioContext` constructor which is used inside the [audio-resampler package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-resampler) to down sample the audio. Again all this only happens with Safari 11 and Edge. But I checked all the params going into the constructor and they are integers. the rest of the stack trace isn't giving me any other clues.

Here's the code I have at this moment:

```
this.audioRecorder.getBuffer((buffers) => {
    // `buffers` is an array of two Float32Arrays representing each channel
    // so create a new buffer and and copy the channel data to it to preserve the audio
    const _buffer = this.audioContext.createBuffer(
      1,
      buffers[0].length,
      this.audioContext.sampleRate
    )

    // _buffer.copyToChannel(buffers[0], 0, 0)

    const channelData = _buffer.getChannelData(0)
    for (let i = 0; i < channelData.length; i++) {
      channelData[i] = buffers[0][i]
    }

    resampler(_buffer, 16000, function(event) {
      const _buffer = event.getAudioBuffer()
      const audioData = {
        sampleRate: _buffer.sampleRate,
        channelData: []
      }

      if (_buffer.duration > 3.0) reject(constants.messages.sampleLength)

      for (var i = 0; i < _buffer.numberOfChannels; i++) {
        audioData.channelData[i] = _buffer.getChannelData(i)
      }

      // resolves a promise outside this code
      resolve(audioData)
    })
  })
```

I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640573/alternative-to-audiocontext-copytochannel-in-safari-and-edge) and tried: `_buffer.getChannelData(0).set(buffers[0])`. Resulted in the same SyntaxError as above.

Lastly, I found this [webkit test .txt](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/LayoutTests/webaudio/offlineaudiocontext-constructor-expected.txt) which seems to suggest the SyntaxError is thrown when a 0 is passed to the OfflineAudioContext constructor. I checked the parameters right before the constructor and they are ***all non-zero***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are constraints on the valid values for the parameters of an `OfflineAudioContext`.  You will have to check the implementation to determine the limits, but if you can create an `AudioBuffer` with those values, then you should be able to construct an `OfflineAudioContext` with those values.  If not, it's a bug in the implementation.

Comment: With Raymond's help I discovered I was attempting to create a buffer with a sample rate outside of Safari's limit. I did indeed find a bug, too. Creating a buffer with `AudioContext` accepts a sample rate down to 22.05 kHz, while using the `OfflineAudioContext` nothing below 44.1 kHz is accepted. The issue with Edge ended up not being related to web audio, but the use of the unsupported `new File` constructor in that browser.